# Check if remote host/port is open - Can't use GNU Netcat nor NMap - RHEL 7

Tags: nmap, rhel7, netcat

At work, the infrastructure team is rolling out new VMs with RHEL7 installed as the base OS. This particular image comes with the `nmap-ncat` version of Netcat and does not have NMap installed. We are precluded from installing anything on the machines.

Previously, we were using the GNU Netcat which have the `-z` option to scan a remote host/port to check if it was open. Something like this:

```
nc -z -v -w 3 remote.host.name 1234
```

How can I achieve the same check with the new `ncat` which does not have the `-z` option on a system where I cannot install `nmap`?

Comment: Why are you checking to see if a port is open/closed? Is this part of a monitoring solution?

Comment: We're working on getting `-z` into Ncat, but it won't be in Red Hat for a while, I'm sure: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/pull/444

Comment: @ewwhite  I have to check if network ACLs are open between point A and point B. For instance: can the app server talk TCP to the DB server on port 1521.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bash allows you to connect to TCP and/or UDP ports by redirecting to special files:

> `/dev/tcp/host/port` If host is a valid hostname or Internet address,
>   and port is an integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to
>   open the corresponding TCP socket.
>
> `/dev/udp/host/port` If host is a valid hostname or Internet address,
>   and port is an integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to
>   open the corresponding UDP socket.
>
> A failure to open or create a file causes the redirection to fail.

So to test if you can connect to port 80 on www.example.com the following should work:

```
echo -n > /dev/tcp/www.example.com/80
```

If the port is blocked you either get a "connection refused" message or a timeout.

Comment: You can telnet to the port too

Comment: Yes, but a minimal install in RHEL 7 does not include the telnet RPM where bash is always present.

Comment: Really? How things have changed.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin plus lots of security guidelines require removal of the telnet client on the basis that using it to log in to something else is insecure; ignoring its vast troubleshooting uses.

Comment: @JasonMartin Pfft

Comment: Not so trivial to scan a range of ports with `/dev/tcp/`

Comment: @JasonMartin also ignoring that you can write your own tcp socket client in bash!

Answer (score 9):

Though Ncat does not yet support `-z`, you can get the same behavior with shell redirection:

```
$ ncat google.com 80 </dev/null >/dev/null && echo "yes"
yes
$ ncat google.com 81 </dev/null >/dev/null && echo "yes"
Ncat: Connection timed out.
$ ncat scanme.nmap.org 1234 </dev/null >/dev/null && echo "yes"
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

The connect timeout can be adjusted with the `-w` option.

EDIT: [Ncat 7.25BETA2](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#7.25BETA2) introduced the `-z` option which works as it does with GNU netcat, but only on single ports. If you need to scan port ranges, you should be using Nmap.

Answer (score 2):

Neither netcat, telnet nor nmap are needed.
Bash is simpler, portable and more efficient.

**Open check**

```
(>/dev/tcp/example.com/80) &>/dev/null && echo "Open"
```

**Open/Closed Check**

```
(>/dev/tcp/example.com/80) &>/dev/null && echo "Open" || echo "Closed"
```

**Port Range Check**

```
for i in $(seq 80 88); do (>/dev/tcp/example.com/80/$i) &>/dev/null && echo $i Open|| echo $i Closed; done
```