# ncat on UDP protocol (RH 7)

Tags: linux, redhat, nmap, netcat

I'm resuming the discussion "[Check if remote host/port is open - Can't use GNU Netcat nor NMap - RHEL 7](https://serverfault.com/q/788934/37681)".
I can't obtain the correct result because on my rh versions (5.6 and 7.1) there isn't the path /dev/tcp nor /dev/udp.

Here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1214763 is explained that it can be resolved using

```
echo | nc -w1  $host $port >/dev/null 2>&1  ;echo $?
```

and it runs with TCP protocol only but not with UDP:

```
echo | nc -w1 -u $host $port >/dev/null 2>&1  ;echo $?
```

Indeed checking an inexistent service it ends with 0.
Using the same ip and port on the RH 5.6 with the old option -z

```
nc -zu $host $port and it ends with 1, correctly.
```

Do you have an idea to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> there isn't the path /dev/tcp nor /dev/udp

That is correct. Those aren't present in your file-system as directories, but when you include both a hostname/ip-address and and port number AND use them in a redirect **bash** will do some magic. As phrased in the manual:

> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections, as described in the following table:
>
> - `/dev/fd/fd`
>                      If `fd` is a valid integer, file descriptor  `fd`  is  duplicated.
> - `/dev/stdin`
>                      File descriptor 0 is duplicated.
> - `/dev/stdout`
>                      File descriptor 1 is duplicated.
> - `/dev/stderr`
>     File descriptor 2 is duplicated.
> - **`/dev/tcp/host/port`**
>     If `host` is a valid hostname or Internet address, and `port`
>     is an integer port number or service name, bash  attempts
>     to open a TCP connection to the corresponding socket.
> - **`/dev/udp/host/port`**
>     If `host` is a valid hostname or Internet address, and `port`
>     is an integer port number or service name, bash  attempts
>     to open a UDP connection to the corresponding socket.

Instead of for instance:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tcp/serverfault.com/80  
ls: cannot access /dev/tcp/serverfault.com/80: No such file or directory
```

try a redirect with <kbd>></kbd>  or <kbd><</kbd>

```
$ echo "" > /dev/tcp/serverfault.com/80
$ echo " " > /dev/tcp/serverfault.com/81
-bash: connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: Hi HBruijn,thanks but it doesn't run. It didn't give me any output, using both a valid couple IP/PORT and an invalid couple.